# Generalized Gaussian binomial and symmetric chain decomposition

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, young-tableaux

**Background**

Let $\mu = (\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_k)$ be a partition, meaning that $\mu_1 \geq \ldots \mu_k \geq 1$. The Young diagram associated to $\mu$ is given by the set $(r,c) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, where $1 \leq r \leq k$ and $1 \leq c \leq \mu_r$. From now on, we identify $\mu$ and its diagram.

The $i^{\textrm{th}}$ *row* of $\mu$ is the subset of elements of the form $(i,c)$ for some $c$, and the $j^{\textrm{th}}$ *column* is the subset of elements of the form $(r,j)$ for some $r$.

A *tableau* with maximal entry $n$ is a map $T : \mu \rightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$. A tableau is said to be *semistandard* if each row is weakly increasing, and each column is strictly increasing.

The *weight* of a tableau, denoted $w(T)$, is the sum of all its entries; $w(T) = \sum_{(r,c) \in \mu} T(r,c)$. The minimal weight is $d := \sum_{i=1}^k i\mu_i$, obtained by filling the first row with 1's, then the second with 2's, and so on. The maximal weight is $D := \sum_{i=1}^k (n+1-i)\mu_i$.

We consider the sequence $(a_j)_{j=0}^{D-d}$  where $a_j$ is the number of semistandard tableaux of shape $\mu$ with maximal entry $n$ and with weight $d + j$.

It has been shown that this sequence is symmetric, $\textrm{i.e.}$ $a_j = a_{(D-d)-j}$, and that it is unimodal, $\textrm{i.e.}$ there exists $0 \leq l \leq D-d$ such that $a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \ldots \leq a_{l} \geq a_{l+1} \geq \ldots \geq a_{D-d}$. As it is symmetric, we have in fact that $l = \lfloor \frac{D-d}{2} \rfloor$.

**My question**

Is there a proof by Symmetric Chain Decomposition that these sequences are symmetric and unimodal?

Let me explain what is such a decomposition.

A *symmetric chain decomposition* of a ranked poset is a partition of the poset into chains $b_{0} < b_{1} < \ldots < b_{p}$ such that:

- $\textrm{rank}(b_{i+1}) = \textrm{rank}(b_i) + 1$;
- $\textrm{rank}(b_0) + \text{rank}(b_p)$ is the rank of a maximal element.

Let $a_j$ be the number of elements of a ranked poset having rank $j$. Clearly, the existence of a symmetric chain decomposition of a poset implies that the sequence $(a_j)_j$ is symmetric and unimodal.

Let $\textrm{SSYT}_n(\mu)$ be the set of all semistandard tableaux of shape $\mu$ with maximal entry $n$. If we order this set by the relation $T < T'$ if $w(T) < w(T')$, we obtain a ranked poset, with maximal rank $D-d$ (so that the minimal element has rank 0).

My question is about the existence of a symmetric chain decomposition of this poset.

For example, let $\mu = (3,1)$ and $n=3$. We have the following ranked poset, where a tableau is smaller than any tableau having a higher rank.

[image]

I am looking for a systematic way to decompose it in symmetric chains.

**Known results**

When $\mu=(m)$, the coefficients $a_j$ is exactly the coefficient of $q^j$ in the Gaussian polynomial ${m+n \choose m}_q$. Using other interpretations of these coefficients, O'Hara, in "Unimodality of Gaussian coefficients: A constructive proof", gave a decomposition of $\textrm{SSYT}_n((m))$ in symmetric chain decomposition.

So my question is about whether her argument has been generalized to other partitions $\mu$. I have not seen any in the litterature, but maybe there is that I haven't found yet! Or maybe the generalisation is easy, but I just don't see it!

**A harder problem**

We can also consider another relation on the set $\textrm{SSYT}_n(\mu)$, where $T \leq_Y T'$ if for all $(r,c) \in \mu$, $T'(r,c) - T(r,c)$ is a nonnegative integer. The goal is then to find a symmetric chain decomposition of this poset, which is a refinement of the poset I gave above in the section .

When $\mu = (m)$, we obtain a poset isomorphic to Young's lattice resticted to partitions contained in a $m \times n$ rectangle. In this case, we only know how to find a symmetric chain decomposition when $m \leq 5$, the case $m = 5$ having been solved last month only!

But maybe we can do in this case for partitions $\mu$ such that $|\mu| \leq 5$? I don't know if such generalizations have been studied either.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't read O'Hara's proof carefully.  The proof doesn't give a symmetric saturation chain decomposition for the natural poset on partitions which fit the $m\times n$ rectangle.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define the partial order on tableaux by comparing weights? In that case, the whole poset is an ordinal sum of antichains, one for each weight, and the existence of a symmetric chain decomposition follows trivially from symmetry and unimodality. I take it you want to compare tableaux entrywise (a la Knutson/Miller)?

Comment: Re: the comments above -- even with the "ordinal sum of antichains" poset it could still be interesting to find an *explicit* (or "algorithmic" or however you want to call it) symmetric chain decomposition.

Comment: I edited my question to add an example and clarify what I am looking for. In the example, it is clear that a symmetric chain decomposition exists, but given $\mu$, what would be a systematic way to do it for any $n$? When $\mu=(m)$, O’Hara gave an answer (for the first order that I gave, not the second), but I am wondering if there is such a construction for other partitions $\mu$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg As Sam Hopkins said, what I am looking for is an algorithmic way to construct the chains. That is, I want that symmetry and unimodality follow from my construction, so I don't want to use those properties to obtain a result. However, I don't know the paper you are talking about, so I don't know if what I am looking for looks like their technique.

Comment: I believe the  result here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659290045V  combined with Kathy O'Hara's construction for the q-binomial case does what you want.

Comment: @Nate I'll look the details, but at first glance it seems to be exactly what I am looking for!